# Use openssl_encrypt to replace Mcrypt for 3DES-ECB encryption

Tags: php, encryption, php-openssl, ecb

I have an encryption method with mycrypt and the cipher is `3des`, mode `ecb`:

```
mcrypt_module_open ( MCRYPT_3DES, '', 'ecb', '' )
```

Now I want to encrypt it using `openssl_encrypt`, and I did not find `des3-ecb` in `openssl_get_cipher_methods()` list.

Comment: Just FYI, you should be using AES not any form of DES.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> now I want to encrypt it use `openssl_encrypt`, and I did not find `des3-ecb` in `openssl_get_cipher_methods()` list.

It's `des-ede3`. Symmetric encryption with a block cipher needs some kind of [mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation). If you look through the list, you will see something like `des-ede3`, `des-ede3-cbc`, `des-ede3-cfb` and `des-ede3-ofb`. CBC, CFB and OFB are all named and the unnamed cipher must be the only other common mode of operation: ECB.

---

**Never use [ECB mode](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/14487/13022)**. It's deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. You should at the very least use a randomized mode like [CBC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/22260/13022) or [CTR](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2378/13022). It is better to authenticate your ciphertexts so that attacks like a [padding oracle attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18185/13022) are not possible. This can be done with authenticated modes like GCM or EAX, or with an [encrypt-then-MAC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022) scheme.

**Don't use Triple DES nowadays.** It only provides at best 112 bit of security even if you use the largest key size of 192 bit. If a shorter key size is used, then it only provides 56 or 57 bits of security. AES would be faster (processors have a special AES-NI instruction set) and even more secure with the lowest key size of 128 bit. There is also a practical limit on the maximum ciphertext size with 3DES. See [Security comparison of 3DES and AES](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/26179/45523).