# MCrypt rijndael-128 to OpenSSL aes-128-ecb conversion

Tags: php, encryption, cryptography, mcrypt, php-openssl

Since Mcrypt is deprecated, I want to use OpenSSL instead in my code since we already using **php 7.0.17** in our server and there's no tell when they upgrade it.

Some third party API (hosted on **PHP 5.x** probably and using **mcrypt**), is taking encrypted data. They've provided methods which they are using to encrypt/decrypt strings.

Here are they

```
$secret = 'a0a7e7997b6d5fcd55f4b5c32611b87c' ;

public function encrypt128($str)
    {
        $block = mcrypt_get_block_size("rijndael_128", "ecb");
        $pad   = $block - (strlen($str) % $block);
        $str .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);

        return base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $secret, $str, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
    }

public function decrypt128($str)
    {
        $str = base64_decode($str);
        $str = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $secret, $str, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);

        $len = strlen($str);
        $pad = ord($str[$len - 1]);

        return substr($str, 0, strlen($str) - $pad);
    }
```

using these methods string `small1` if encrypted becomes `v7IXp5vVaFVXXlt/MN8BVw==`

---

We want to use `openssl_encrypt` in our side such that if we encrypt same string with OpenSSL it must give same results as Mcrypt. I've researched that mcrypt using **rijndael-128** Mode **ecb** should be compatible with OpenSSL `aes-128-ecb`.

For last few hours, I've been trying to make my own method to encrypt strings serving same result by using OpenSSL. So far I've come to this

```
public function sslEncrypt128($str)
{
    $secret = 'a0a7e7997b6d5fcd55f4b5c32611b87c';
    return base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($str, 'aes-128-ecb', $secret, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA));
}
```

But it produces different string `SxJ3+EdaeItZx3/EwGTUbw==` for same as above input. I don't know if it is flag's problem or padding's, any pointers will be welcome.

I've added the code here to test online https://3v4l.org/v2J2N

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ECB mode has some serious security problems.  Be **very** sure that it is appropriate for your specific application.  Generally CBC mode or CTR mode will be more secure.  See [Electronic Codebook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.290) for an illustration (literally) of the problem.

Comment: Also see [Upgrading my encryption library from Mcrypt to OpenSSL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43329513/608639), [Replace Mcrypt with OpenSSL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9993909/608639) and [Preparing for removal of Mcrypt in PHP 7.2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42696657/608639), [Use openssl_encrypt to replace Mcrypt for 3DES-ECB encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39467008/608639) (it uses ECM mode).

Comment: Note: Base64 data is fine for computers but for developers to understand anything from the data a per-byte representation is needed, hex meets that need, Base64 does not.

Comment: In your code example I was able to produce the same output in sslEncrypt128 by changing `aes-128-ecb` to `aes-256-ecb`.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelButler. It solved my problem. 
`MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` with `MCRYPT_MODE_ECB` mode is same as open ssl `aes-256-ecb`. You can Post your finding as Answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your specific example I've found that by changing `aes-128-ecb` to `aes-256-ecb`, it produces the same output as the legacy `mcrypt_encrypt`.

Comment: I believe Mcrypt provides *block sizes* of 128, 192 and 256 bits. AES only provides the 128 block size. My guess is, `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` is probably referring to Rijndael with 128-bit block size, which is AES. The key size is a different matter, and that is what the `256` denotes in OpenSSL's `AES-256-CBC`. If using a Standard Cryptographic Algorithm Name (SCAN), then the Mcrypt algorithm name for the cipher instance would be similar to `Rijndael-128(256)/CBC`.

Answer (score 12):

Here is what worked for me:

```
<?php

$str = 'Content';
if (strlen($str) % 16) {
    $str = str_pad($str, strlen($str) + 16 - strlen($str) % 16, "\0");
}

$key = 'KEY';
if (strlen($key) % 16) {
    $key = str_pad($key, strlen($key) + 16 - strlen($key) % 16, "\0");
}

$res1 = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $str, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
echo strToHex($res1) . ' | mcrypt_encrypt';

echo "<hr>";
echo strToHex(openssl_decrypt($res1, "aes-128-ecb", $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_NO_PADDING)) . ' | openssl_decrypt';

echo "<hr>";

$res2 = openssl_encrypt($str, "aes-128-ecb", $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_NO_PADDING);
echo strToHex($res2) . ' | openssl_encrypt';

echo "<hr>";
echo strToHex(openssl_decrypt($res2, "aes-128-ecb", $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_NO_PADDING)) . ' | openssl_decrypt';


function strToHex($string) {
    $hex = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) {
        $ord     = ord($string[$i]);
        $hexCode = dechex($ord);
        $hex     .= substr('0' . $hexCode, -2);
    }

    return strToUpper($hex);
}
```

Comment: dude thank you! the padding on the data & key made it match exactly what i was getting from the mcrypt way.

Comment: Nice! But instead of `strToHex` you can use `bin2hex` native PHP function

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the key was expected to be used as hex (it already is in hex format) not as a string to be converted to hex.

---

mcrypt:

`mcrypt` does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding **but the padding is being explicitly added prior to mcrypt**.

The encryption `v7IXp5vVaFVXXlt/MN8BVw==` is the correct encryption based on PKCS#7 padding. ECB mode and the key as a string.

See: [mcrypt - AES CALCULATOR](http://extranet.cryptomathic.com/aescalc?key=6130613765373939376236643566636435356634623563333236313162383763&iv=00000000000000000000000000000000&input=736d616c6c310a0a0a0a0a0a0a0a0a0a&mode=ecb&action=Encrypt&output=02FD933A42E14014976854E479B67F07).

In hex, notice the data padding is clearly visible:
`key:       6130613765373939376236643566636435356634623563333236313162383763`
`data:      736D616C6C310A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A`
`encrypted: BFB217A79BD56855575E5B7F30DF0157`

In Base64:
`encrypted: v7IXp5vVaFVXXlt/MN8BVw==`

---

OpenSSL:

Notice the key is 256-bits but the OpenSSL call with "aes-128-ecb" seems to imply a 128-but key. So the keys don't match.

See: [OpenSSL - AES CALCULATOR](http://extranet.cryptomathic.com/aescalc?key=61306137653739393762366435666364&iv=00000000000000000000000000000000&input=736D616C6C310A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A&mode=ecb&action=Encrypt&output=BFB217A79BD56855575E5B7F30DF0157)

In hex, notice the data padding is clearly visible:
`key:       61306137653739393762366435666364`
`data:      736D616C6C310A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A`
`encrypted: 4B1277F8475A788B59C77FC4C064D46F`

In Base64:
`encrypted: SxJ3+EdaeItZx3/EwGTUbw==`