# PHP 7.2 openssl_encrypt and mcrypt_encrypt generate different values

Tags: php, openssl, mcrypt

I am migrating all the functions of my project that encrypt data and work with mcrypt to openssl.

Making tests I find that, encrypting the same data with the same keys I get different results.

When decrypting I get the correct result with boths functions; the problem is that I share this information with an external provider and only successfully decrypt the data if I encrypt with mcrypt.

This is the test code:

```
// Configuration.
$data = 'FOO';
$secret = '111222333444555666777888';
$iv = 'ABCDEFGH';

// Encrytp & decrypt with mcrypt.
$encMcrypt = bin2hex(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $secret, utf8_encode($data),  MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
$decMcrypt = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $secret, hex2bin($encMcrypt), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

// Encrytp & decrypt with openssl.
$encOpenSSL = bin2hex(openssl_encrypt(utf8_encode($data), 'DES-EDE3-CBC', $secret, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv));
$decOpenSSL = openssl_decrypt(hex2bin($encOpenSSL), 'DES-EDE3-CBC', $secret, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);

// Result.
echo "mcrypt encrypt: $encMcrypt <br>";
echo "openssl encrypt: $encOpenSSL <br>";
echo "mcrypt decrypt: $decMcrypt <br>";
echo "openssl decrypt: $decOpenSSL";
```

Result:

```
mcrypt encrypt: 3f9bd8d5f844ff67
openssl encrypt: b2f4b9aeb07e1ca4
mcrypt decrypt: FOO
openssl decrypt: FOO
```

Does anyone know why it is because they get different results?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that [`mcrypt_encrypt`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php) / [`mcrypt_decrypt`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php) uses [Zero-Padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#Zero_padding) and [`openssl_encrypt`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php) / [`openssl_decrypt`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-decrypt.php) uses [PKCS7-Padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS#5_and_PKCS#7). This can be easily verified by applying Zero-Padding for `openssl`: For this, PKCS7-Padding must be disabled with the flag `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING` (*important*: despite the name, this flag doesn't mean that Zero-Padding is used, but that no padding is applied at all), and the plaintext must be padded with `0`-values to the next integer multiple of the blocksize (`8` bytes for Triple-DES) unless the length already corresponds to an integer multiple of the blocksize:

```
<?php

function zeroPadding($data, $size) {
    $oversize = strlen($data) % $size;
    return $oversize == 0 ? $data : ($data . str_repeat("\0", $size - $oversize)); 
}

// Something is wronguration.
$data = 'FOO';

$secret = '111222333444555666777888';
$iv = 'ABCDEFGH';

// Encrytp & decrypt with mcrypt.
$encMcrypt = bin2hex(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $secret, utf8_encode($data), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
$decMcrypt = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $secret, hex2bin($encMcrypt), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

// Encrytp & decrypt with openssl.
$encOpenSSLZeroPadding = bin2hex(openssl_encrypt(utf8_encode(zeroPadding($data, 8)), 'DES-EDE3-CBC', $secret, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $iv));
$decOpenSSLZeroPadding = openssl_decrypt(hex2bin($encOpenSSLZeroPadding), 'DES-EDE3-CBC', $secret, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $iv);

// Result.
echo "data padded: " . bin2hex(zeroPadding($data, 8)) . "<br>";
echo "mcrypt encrypt: $encMcrypt <br>";
echo "openssl encrypt: $encOpenSSLZeroPadding <br>";
echo "mcrypt decrypt: $decMcrypt <br>";
echo "mcrypt decrypt: " . bin2hex($decMcrypt) . "<br>";
echo "openssl decrypt: $decOpenSSLZeroPadding" . "<br>";
echo "openssl decrypt: " . bin2hex($decOpenSSLZeroPadding);
```

with the following output:

```
data padded: 464f4f0000000000
mcrypt encrypt: 3f9bd8d5f844ff67
openssl encrypt: 3f9bd8d5f844ff67
mcrypt decrypt: FOO
mcrypt decrypt: 464f4f0000000000
openssl decrypt: FOO
openssl decrypt: 464f4f0000000000
```

Instead of using a Zero-Padding in the `openssl`-context, a PKCS7-Padding could be used in the `mcrypt`-context. No matter which of the two variants is used, with identical padding `mcrypt` and `openssl` results are identical!

It should be noted (see the hexadecimal output) that `mcrypt` doesn't remove the Zero-Padding during decryption (unlike `openssl` which removes the PKCS7-Padding during decryption). Also, Zero-Padding is [unreliable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#Zero_padding) compared to PKCS7-Padding. If the requirements allow it (which in your case is probably not the case because of the external provider), PKCS7-Padding should therefore be used.

Furthermore, both posted variants use the same algorithm, namely [Triple-DES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES) in [CBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_(CBC))-mode. Triple-DES has a blocksize of `8` bytes and a keysize of `24` bytes. Triple-DES is not identical to [DES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard), but is based on DES in the sense that it consists of three DES-runs (encryption-decryption-encryption = ede). `mcrypt` specifies Triple-DES/CBC with two parameters, `MCRYPT_3DES` (Triple-DES) and `MCRYPT_MODE_CBC` (CBC-mode), while `openssl` uses only one parameter, `DES-EDE3-CBC`.

There are several [Keying-Options](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES#Keying_options) for Triple-DES. `3TDEA` uses three independent DES keys and is specified in the context of `openssl` with `DES-EDE3-CBC`, which expects a `24` bytes key, `2TDEA` uses two independent keys and can be specified in the context of `openssl` alternatively with `DES-EDE-CBC`, which expects a `16` bytes key.

Triple-DES is much slower than the modern AES, but has a comparable security. As with padding, you should switch to AES if possible.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response :) I am working with my provider to migrate the system to AES. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, both methods use different algorithms, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39467008/use-openssl-encrypt-to-replace-mcrypt-for-3des-ecb-encryption). You should try and use `des-ede3` as openssl cipher method, which is the equivalent of mcrypt's `MCRYPT_3DES`.

Comment: Both variants, `mcrypt` and `openssl`, use the _same_ algorithm Triple-DES with CBC-mode. `mycrypt` uses however two parameters for specification (`MCRYPT_3DES`, `MCRYPT_MODE_CBC`), while `openssl` requires only one parameter (`DES-EDE3-CBC`).

Answer (score 1):

Mcrypt and openssl are two different ciphers, so they encrypt and decrypt data in different ways.

You can use openSSL's des-ede3 method, however you should really be using AES: [Security Comparison of AES and DES](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/26179/security-comparsion-of-3des-and-aes)

If your external provider is using mcrypt_decrypt to decrypt the data you send them, then they won't be able to decrypt data that is encrypted with openssl, and vice-versa.

Your external provider will need to change the way the decrypt the data as well if you move to the more secure AES openSSL encryption.

(on a side note, it's good that you're moving to openssl - mcrypt is abandonware circa php 7.1)

Comment: *If your external provider is using mcrypt_decrypt to decrypt the data you send them, then they won't be able to decrypt data that is encrypted with openssl, and vice-versa*: Data encrypted with `mcrypt` can easily be decrypted with `openssl` (and vice versa) if the padding is properly considered. And: *if you move to the more secure AES openSSL encryption*: The security of Triple-DES (unlike DES) and AES is *comparable*. However, AES is *newer and more modern* and *significantly faster* than Triple-DES, which are the main reasons for switching to AES.